# Sakai 10 clog not compiling :(

Tags: compilation, sakai, clog

I'm having a little trouble on compiling the clog tool for sakai 10...

https://github.com/adrianfish/clog/issues/5

I suspect adrian is busy on the 11 build at the moment, but I'm wondering if it's actually something that can be fixed by the user, or maybe others have hit this and are doing something simple that I don't know about..?

Basically the current stable version of clog (0.9.3 -https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/CLOG/Home) doesn't compile for the sakai 10 code base, there is what looks to be a related issue (CLOG-113) here...

https://github.com/adrianfish/clog/pull/3

but I'm not sure if the sakai-10 repository for maven exists as the error you get for compiling the sakai-10 branch of clog (https://github.com/adrianfish/clog/tree/sakai-10) is as follows:

```
bash-3.2$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.sakaiproject.clog:clog:0.9.5-SNAPSHOT (/usr/local/sakai/sakai-src-10.0/clog-0.9.5-sakai-10branch/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.sakaiproject:master:pom:10.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 12, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Has anyone managed to get clog to compile on sakai 10? This is a bit of a blocker for our sakai 10 deployment :(

Edit: (Also see "further edit" for solution)

After trying the suggestion (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24769111/3737856) below I get this error

```
*---snip---*
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/17/commons-parent-17.pom (31 KB at 507.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/7/apache-7.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/7/apache-7.pom (15 KB at 320.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/projectlombok/lombok/0.11.6/lombok-0.11.6.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/projectlombok/lombok/0.11.6/lombok-0.11.6.pom (2 KB at 34.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] CLOG .............................................. SUCCESS [  7.693 s]
[INFO] CLOG API .......................................... FAILURE [  3.520 s]
[INFO] CLOG IMPL ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CLOG PACK ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CLOG HELP ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CLOG TOOL ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.166 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-16T10:11:38+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project clog-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.sakaiproject.clog:clog-api:jar:0.9.5-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect depend   encies at org.sakaiproject.kernel:sakai-kernel-api:jar:10.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.sakaiproject.kernel:sakai-kernel-api:jar:10.0: Could not find arti   fact org.sakaiproject:kernel:pom:10.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :clog-api
```

I have built the current sakai 10 release build from source (building the master directory then the root), placed the clog source in the root and built it there. This usually works.

In addition I also tried changing in the clog pom:

```
<name>CLOG</name>
<groupId>org.sakaiproject.clog</groupId>
<artifactId>clog</artifactId>
<version>0.9.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

to:

```
<name>CLOG</name>
<groupId>org.sakaiproject.clog</groupId>
<artifactId>clog</artifactId>
<version>0.9.5</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

building with this and the other suggested change resulted in this error:

```
-bash-3.2$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/master/10.0/master-10.0.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/master/10.0/master-10.0.pom (59 KB at 172.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] CLOG API
[INFO] CLOG IMPL
[INFO] CLOG PACK
[INFO] CLOG HELP
[INFO] CLOG TOOL
[INFO] CLOG
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CLOG API 0.9.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] CLOG API .......................................... FAILURE [  1.374 s]
[INFO] CLOG IMPL ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CLOG PACK ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CLOG HELP ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CLOG TOOL ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CLOG .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.584 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-16T10:19:02+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project clog-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.sakaiproject.clog:clog-api:jar:0.9.5-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.sakaiproject.kernel:sakai-kernel-api:jar:10.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.sakaiproject.kernel:sakai-kernel-api:jar:10.0: Failure to find org.sakaiproject:kernel:pom:10.0 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Additionally... I notice the donwloads are referencing maven2 repositories, I don't suppose that makes any difference, I'm definitely using maven3...

```
-bash-3.2$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T17:37:52+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven2/current
Java version: 1.6.0_27, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.18-348.18.1.el5", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Further edit:

D'OH!!!

It works now, I changed the pom only in the way suggested (10-SNAPSHOT -> 10) and --> "compiled as root" <-- what I was doing before was compiling as a non-super user, it looks like the initial build was compiled with root and/or I have permissions wrong somewhere, but clog is now compiling.

I think I'm going to submit a pull request to adrian for the pom change though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Clog is setup correctly. You need to have the parent that this is depending on checked out (master) and built locally if you're doing a full source compile. Then you can build clog.

https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=93028745

Optionally you can change the version to 10.0 (which has released dependencies) and clog will compile. For instance:

```
--- a/pom.xml
+++ b/pom.xml
@@ -12,7 +12,7 @@
     <parent>
         <groupId>org.sakaiproject</groupId>
         <artifactId>master</artifactId>
-        <version>10.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
+        <version>10.0</version>
         <relativePath>../master/pom.xml</relativePath>
     </parent>
```

The externals for the tools which are on nightly and are known to work on 10 is here.
https://source.sakaiproject.org/svn/sakai/branches/sakai-trunk-experimental/.externals