# Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.sakaiproject:master:pom:10-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath'

Tags: compilation, tags, pom.xml, sakai

I've just checked out the 10.2 tag and received the titular error after a "mvn clean install" on < sakai-root/master > then "mvn clean install" on < sakai-root >

I've tried googling around non-resolvable parent POM type errors:

[Non-resolvable parent POM for Could not find artifact and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926952/non-resolvable-parent-pom-for-could-not-find-artifact-and-parent-relativepath)

http://collab.sakaiproject.org/pipermail/sakai-dev/2012-June/017765.html

etc....

But the basic gist of them is you need to set the "relativePath" setting for the parent differently (to point at the pom.xml) or you need to change the "version"/"artifactId"... I've also run into a similar problem on the CLOG tool source:

[Sakai 10 clog not compiling :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756469/sakai-10-clog-not-compiling)

For sakai as a whole, when you check out a new tag, what should the xml settings be in order for it to compile properly if you receive this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug. The base pom.xml should have had consistent versions of 10.2 and not 10-SNAPSHOT. The pom.xml has been fixed:

https://source.sakaiproject.org/svn/sakai/tags/sakai-10.2/pom.xml